# How to solve Empty Form data in Netlify Function

Tags: javascript, forms, function, netlify

I have a function that is triggered on submission-created.

Although the function is triggered I do not receive the data in the event.body as I have seen in some posts.

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  console.log(event);
  console.log(context);
  console.log("Form submission Triggered");
.
.
.
}
```

The code above is logging:

```
{ callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop: [Getter/Setter],
done: [Function: done],
succeed: [Function: succeed],
fail: [Function: fail],
logGroupName: ‘/aws/lambda/3dc25af66d2e967e42e29324f6a413386dd16a978a23f8bc2c8b21d32b647971’,
logStreamName: ‘2019/08/10/[$LATEST]0bf7a2b7fbc74927ba2fa6354cc10f6c’,
functionName: ‘3dc25af66d2e967e42e29324f6a413386dd16a978a23f8bc2c8b21d32b647971’,
memoryLimitInMB: ‘1024’,
functionVersion: ‘$LATEST’,
getRemainingTimeInMillis: [Function: getRemainingTimeInMillis],
clientContext:
{ custom:
{ netlify: ‘eyJzaXRlX3VybCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vdmlzdWFsZXllcy5sb2NleWUuaW8ifQ==’ } },
invokeid: ‘057082a6-a023-417b-9753-40d563d41735’,
awsRequestId: ‘057082a6-a023-417b-9753-40d563d41735’,
invokedFunctionArn: 'arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:67
```

Any clue? Moreover, the code locally is running with no errors